# How to prevent refactoring when I double-click & paste over a variable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, productivity-power-tools

I regularly copy something, double-click something else (generally a variable), and paste over it with ctrl-v. After installing productivity power tools, occasionally (I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact circumstances) it will open up the header file of the variable I pasted over, and refactor it to what I pasted. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking on the variable with Ctrl held, the power tools will navigate to the declaration of the variable. (Which is a feature that I appreciate)

You have two choices:

- do not press Ctrl before you have marked the variable with double clicking
- disable the *"Ctrl+Click go to definition"* feature under `Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools`

Comment: ahhh I see! I realize that I often go "ctrl, double-click variable, V", which is what causes it